# How to create object as parent of Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to create a new element for my unity project but I need unity to render my whole object as a UI object how do I make this happen. My current script thus far.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class OptionSwitch : MonoBehaviour {

    [MenuItem ("GameObject/UI/Switch")]
    static void Switch(){
        GameObject go = new GameObject("switch");
        go.transform.parent = Selection.activeTransform;
        go.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

It will be a option switch with a button on either side of a textbox indicating the active option.

I did more research and came up with this code.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class OptionSwitch : MonoBehaviour {

    [MenuItem ("GameObject/UI/Switch")]
    static void Switch(){

        if (GameObject.Find ("Canvas") != null) {

            // Define Components
            GameObject Canvas   = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
            GameObject Switch   = new GameObject("Switch");
            GameObject Previous = new GameObject("Previous Button");
            GameObject Next     = new GameObject("Next Button");
            GameObject Text     = new GameObject("Textbox");


            // Place Switch
            Switch.transform.parent = Canvas.transform;
            Switch.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

            // Place Previous Button
            Previous.transform.parent = Switch.transform;
            Previous.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

            // Place Text Field
            Text.transform.parent = Switch.transform;
            Text.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

            // Place Next Field
            Next.transform.parent = Switch.transform;
            Next.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's going now now? What works and what doesn't? Also, to be clear, you want the new created GameObject to be under the UI Canvas or to be a parent of the UI Canvas? Why do you have `Selection.activeTransform`? There is just too many questions about your question.

Comment: @Programmer I want the object "switch" to be a child of the UI Canvas, I know that you can find an object by name, but I want to design it so that it finds the canvas even if the name is changed, that's what doesn't work, I continued looking and found a way to make the object the child of the canvas, but not when the canvas isn't called "Canvas".

Comment: Your comment actually explains your problem more than your question. Check my answer.

Comment: When I said close the answer, I meant you you accept is as answer not delete it. That answer could help many people out there. Please, undelete it and mark it as the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546130/unity-how-to-change-colors-of-ui-button-via-script Thanks.

Comment: My apologies, it was a mistake on my part, and i will rectify that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have have to find the `Canvas` GameObject first. The `Canvas` GameObject has `Canvas` component attached to it. So, you use `FindObjectOfType` to find the `Canvas` component. You can then then convert the instance of that `Canvas` script into a GameObject. The fix for your original code:

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/UI/Switch")]
static void Switch()
{
    //Create new GameObject
    GameObject go = new GameObject("switch");


    //Find Canvas in the Scene
    Canvas canvas = (Canvas)GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(Canvas));

    //Get Canvas GameObject
    GameObject canvasGameObject = canvas.gameObject;

    //Make the new GameObject child of the Canvas
    go.transform.parent = canvasGameObject.transform;
    go.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

    //Change the new GameObject Layer to UI
    go.layer = 5; //Or go.layer = canvasGameObject.layer;

    //Add Rect Transform to it
    go.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
}
```