# Change colors of UI button via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the colours on a UI Button using this line of code.

```
prev.GetComponent<Button>().colors.normalColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

but I'm receiving this error

> Assets/_Scripts/OptionSwitch.cs(28,53): error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.UI.Selectable.colors'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

I've tried storing both the button and the color as variables before calling them but it doesn't change the error code.

**EDIT**:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.Sprites;

public class OptionSwitch : MonoBehaviour {

    ColorBlock colorBlock = new ColorBlock();
    colorBlock.normalColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    [MenuItem ("GameObject/UI/Switch")]
    static void Switch(){

        if (GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof(Canvas)) != null) {

            Canvas canvas = (Canvas)GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof(Canvas));

            // Define Previous Button
            GameObject prev = new GameObject ("Previous", typeof(Button));
            prev.layer = 5;
            prev.AddComponent<Image> ();
            prev.transform.parent = canvas.transform;

            prev.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource<Sprite>("UI/Skin/UISprite.psd");
            prev.GetComponent<Button>().colors = buttonColors;

            // Define Previous Button Image
            GameObject previm = new GameObject("Previous Image", typeof(RawImage));
            previm.layer = 5;
            previm.transform.parent = prev.transform;

        } else {

            // Create Canvas
            GameObject canvas = new GameObject("Canvas", typeof(Canvas));
            canvas.AddComponent<CanvasScaler> ();
            canvas.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster> ();
            canvas.layer = 5;
            canvas.GetComponent<Canvas> ().renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
            canvas.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

            // Create Event System
            GameObject eventsystem = new GameObject("EventSystem", typeof(EventSystem));
            eventsystem.AddComponent<StandaloneInputModule>();
            eventsystem.AddComponent<TouchInputModule>();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the `colors` not the `normalColor`. The `GetComponent<Button>().colors` returns `ColorBlock`.

So, create a new instance of `ColorBlock`. Modify `normalColor` from that `ColorBlock` then assign that `ColorBlock` to the `GetComponent<Button>().colors`.

Full example:

```
ColorBlock colorBlock = new ColorBlock();
colorBlock.normalColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

prev.GetComponent<Button>().colors = colorBlock;
```

This will overwrite your other color settings. To preserver them, create your `ColorBlock` from `prev.GetComponent<Button>().colors;`

```
ColorBlock colorBlock = prev.GetComponent<Button>().colors;
colorBlock.normalColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

prev.GetComponent<Button>().colors = colorBlock;
```

You can also modify the color properties below:

```
colorBlock.pressedColor = new Color(1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
colorBlock.highlightedColor = new Color(0f, 1f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
colorBlock.disabledColor = new Color(0f, 0f, 1, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I'm getting errors Assets/_Scripts/OptionSwitch.cs(10,28): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration and Assets/_Scripts/OptionSwitch.cs(10,43): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `0' in class, struct, or interface member declaration,

Comment: Which line of code? The code I posted above is working perfectly fine on my side. You are doing something wrong. I suggest you create a new script to make sure you got this right. If possible, copy the code from the answer directly.

Comment: I did copy it directly it's line 10, is there a non standard namespace you are using to define a colorblock?

Comment: **"it's line 10"** because I can see line 10 from here. Put Edit in your question and add the new code you have. That' s the only way to find out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it's this line "colorBlock.normalColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);" I've added the whole code in my question

Comment: That line of code compiled on my side.Put `colorBlock.normalColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` inside a function. You **can't** change a property of a class or struct outside a function.

Comment: I just realized that, I'm just getting back into using unity and I've forgotten a few things.

Answer (score 0):

```
ColorBlock colorBlock = new ColorBlock();

colorBlock.normalColor = Color.yellow;
colorBlock.colorMultiplier = 1;
gameManager.setCurrentLevelBoardRef.currentButtonArray[numbersToColor[i]]
    .GetComponent<Button>().colors= colorBlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use button's image component and modify its color to change the background color of the button. To achieve this, you may use the following code:

```
btn.GetComponent<Image>().color = yourColor;
btn.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Alternatively, you can utilize a `ColorBlock`. By copying the existing color properties of the another button, you can adjust the `normalColor` component before applying it back to the button:

```
ColorBlock colorBlock = btn1.GetComponent<Button>().colors;
colorBlock.normalColor = yourColor;
btn2.GetComponent<Button>().colors = colorBlock;
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't know what's up with all the `.GetComponents` but there is another way too !

This method works for when you have multiple buttons and want to just change their colours or make them disappear.

```
Color.red , Color.grey , ...

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    alchemistVoScript.gatedButtons [i].image.color = Color.clear;
    alchemistVoScript.gatedButtons [i].interactable = false;

}
```