# unable to change UIButton color in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, uibutton

I have a UI button in unity who's color i want to change via script,but get error(**Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.UI.Selectable.colors'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable**) when call the method to change the color of the button when the UIbutton is pressed.

CODE

```
public Button DrumButton;

public void DrumButtonClicked()
    {
        DrumButton.colors.normalColor = new Color(0.22f, 0.22f, 0.22f, 1f);
    }
```

Comment: A google on your error message, and the very first result... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/792008/how-to-change-normal-color-highlighted-color-etc-i.html

Comment: And the very 2nd one.... http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/changing-the-color-of-a-button-in-script.344121/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity How to change colors of ui button via script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546130/unity-how-to-change-colors-of-ui-button-via-script)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change the colors variable directly. It is something that is managed by Unity, and they don't want you to do that. Instead, you have to store it in a temporary variable before changing it. Try this:

```
ColorBlock drumColors = DrumButton.colors;
drumColors.normalColor = new Color(0.22f, 0.22f, 0.22f, 1f);
DrumButton.colors = normalColor;
```

Comment: Do not answer duplicated question! Read the comments.